# Database Design: Circular reference and how to correct it

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, database-design, circular-reference

[image: Database design: an item is related to client and employee. And employee is related to client]

Is this a circular reference? If so, how can I improve my model?

Comment: I think some of your cardinalities might be wrong. Judging by the "fk" labels it looks like Employee and Item both reference Client; Item also references Employee. I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with that but your cardinalities seem to contradict the "fk" labels.

Comment: Thanks @nvogel. I've corrected the cardinalities.

Comment: Looks ok to me. I don't see anything else that needs correcting. There is no circular dependency because Client is not dependent on anything else

Comment: Should "itemID (int, fk) on table Item not be "EmployeeID"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any circular references. I interpret the data model to say:

```
An Item belongs to exactly 1 Client
An Item belongs to 0 or 1 Employee
An Employee belongs to exactly 1 Client
```

A circular reference would add `An Employees to exactly 1 Item`.

In the comments, you said than an item always belongs to the same client as it's employee, but not all items belong to an employee.

There are a few ways to model this.

What I would avoid is having ClientID as a not-null foreign key relationship on Item - this duplicates the logic that "an item without an explicit client ID inherits the client ID from its employee". It's not expressive (people reading the schema would not be able to figure that out), and opens up bugs.

One option is to make the cardinality of both `item->employee` and `item-> client` optional (i.e. 0..1). Your convention would then be `if an item has a client relationship, it may not have an employee relationship`, and `if an item has an employee relationship, it may not have an explicit client relationship; the client is determined by the employee.` You can't cleanly express this in your schema, and would have to build this into your data access code.

Another option is to create two type of item, one with a clientID foreign relationship, and one with an employeeId foreign relationship. This is much more expressive from a schema point of view - presumably there is some business concept you can use to name the tables. However, if `Item` has lots of attributes, you're duplicating a lot.

Finally, you could store the relationship of items to either client or employee in separate joining table:

```
Item
-------
ItemID
...

ItemEmployees
-----------------
ItemID
EmployeeID

ItemClients
----------
ItemID
ClientID
```

This avoids the duplication of attributes on Item, but is less expressive because it uses a pattern more commonly used for many-to-many relationships, and doesn't explicitly declare "either or".

Comment: Thanks @NevilleKuyt. The item always belong to the same client as its employee but an item could belong to a client and not belong to an employee. In that case how could I remove the "conditional" duplication?

Comment: If an item may not always belong to an employee, your cardinality appears wrong - I think it should be 0..1. Can you update the question, and I'll respond in the answer?